# Apache Camel throttling working intermittently

Tags: apache-camel, throttling

We need our Camel app to raise an exception and reject incoming request if the msg count exceeds specified threshold (i.e., allow 4 requests in 10 sec time span).
Below is the configuration we have in our camel context file right after jetty front side http listener.

```
<throttle timePeriodMillis="10000" rejectExecution="true">
    <constant>4</constant>
    <to uri="bean:someEndPoint"/>
</throttle>
```

When we invoke Camel app via jmeter, throttle happens for 5th request and subsequent requests too... however, throttle keeps happening forever even after the expiry of 10 sec time span.  While, some other times throttle doesn't happen at all during the newer 10 sec time span windows.

Please help here.

Thx
Ramesh

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?